# Mac OSx 7zcat command not found

Tags: macos

I am trying to execute a Makefile script and my Mac complains about 7zcat, although I already have 7z installed.

```
/bin/sh: 7zcat: command not found
```

Any thoughts on what's missing on my system? Thank you!

Comment: See: https://searchcode.com/file/40178572/7zcat

Answer (score 1):

I have never used 7zcat before.
However, it looks like it needs to be installed on your system.
https://github.com/essentialkaos/7zcat

Also, after you download install 7zcat you have to give it execute permission with chmod. Finally, you have to execute it by calling its full path for example if you installed it to the directory you are in you would run ./7zcat file.7z or you would add the path to the file to your environment's $PATH variable.

I hope this helps. You might have to do some more research though.

Comment: I also found this repo, however when trying to install it on Max I get the message: sudo ./install.sh 
Password:

\e[36mYou really want install latest version of 7ZCat? (y/N):\e[0m
> y

\e[31mUnsupported platform\e[0m

Answer (score 0):

When you open a Terminal window and type `7zcat` and hit enter, what happens? Same message? Well, if you cannot use it, why should `make` be able to use it? Where and how have you installed 7z? Is the folder with the 7z binaries in your `PATH`? Since if it isn't, of course the command won't be found.

When the system shall run a command, it will search for this command in the directories stored in the `PATH` variable. Execute `echo $PATH` in terminal and you will get a colon separated list of directories; only these directories are searched for binaries. So either you must move your binaries to one of these (or put a symlink to one of these) or add the directory with these binaries to the `PATH`.

Yet there is no official 7z command line installer for MacOS, which brings me back to the original questions "Where and how have you installed 7z?" And are you sure that whatever you installed even includes a `7zcat`?

Comment: @Crista23 What makes you believe that the p7zip ships a 7zcat? This package contains the binaries 7z, 7za and 7zr and nothing else. What kind of makefile are you trying to run?